# list splicing variable assignments automation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variable-assignment

Imagine that you have a list of strings.

```
lst = ['a','b17','c','dz','e','ff','e3','e66']
```

you want to seperate those strings into individual variables

`a = lst[:7]
 b = lst[7:14]
 c = lst[14:21]`

Im wondering if there is a pythonic way of handling this instead of spending time typing out every single list splice.

Comment: Using variables here is a very poor design choice, use a list of a dict instead

Comment: What do you do when you finish the alphabet and still have items in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to produce the slices and unpack them to your desired variables:

```
a, b, c = (lst[i:i+7] for i in range(0, 21, 7))
```

But that would produce an error of too many items to unpack if there are more than 21 items in the list, so it's better to use a list comprehension to keep it a list instead of individual variables:

```
[lst[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(lst), 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
def f(lst,n):
   l=[]
   range_=list(range(0,len(lst),n))
   for x,y in zip(range_,range_[1:]):
      l.append(lst[x:y])
   return l
print(f(lst,7))
```

Output with `lst` as:

```
lst = ['a','b17','c','dz','e','ff','e3','e66']*5
```

Is:

```
[['a', 'b17', 'c', 'dz', 'e', 'ff', 'e3'], ['e66', 'a', 'b17', 'c', 'dz', 'e', 'ff'], ['e3', 'e66', 'a', 'b17', 'c', 'dz', 'e'], ['ff', 'e3', 'e66', 'a', 'b17', 'c', 'dz'], ['e', 'ff', 'e3', 'e66', 'a', 'b17', 'c']]
```